# Is there something like package.json and package-lock.json that can be used for any programming language?

Tags: artifactory, package.json, package-lock.json

In JavaScript, package.json and package-lock.json can be used to specify desired versions and locked versions. In Python, there is a similar solution in Poetry.

Is there any similar tool that is built to be used with any language, and that I can use with JFrog Artifactory?

Comment: "can be used" as in "will actually work right now" or as in "could potentially be developed"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most major programming languages have their own package type and package manager. There's currently no single tool to rule them all.

[JFrog Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/) has an extensive [package management](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Package+Management) system, supporting many package types (~30 and counting). Refer to the documentation to find more information on how to use each package type.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no tool that can provide this with any language. Package management is always language/framework dependent. From the C guys that just use the system package manager to JavaScript that uses NPM. There are many solutions to the problem of managing dependencies. I see it as a feature of the language that I'm using as also argued by this [StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/20/what-is-rust-and-why-is-it-so-popular/#h-the-rust-ecosystem).